# EJB 2.1 Performance Issue and Verifying Root Cause

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb-2.x

I am working on a legacy J2EE project that is having serious performance problems under load. Here are some of the features that we are using.

- EJB 2.1 (released in 2003)
- EJB CMPs
- JSPs
- Session and Entity Beans. (No remote EJB calls)
- Jboss 5

The server's CPU usage never goes above 25%  (on a 4 core machine), and the application stops responding to any request. The database server doesn't even have a load. It is possible that since it never goes above 25% that the problem is outside of the application.

I am currently under the belief that application is running at 100%, but because the application isn't properly multithreaded it won't utilize more than one core. The EJB spec we are on wasn't even out when multi-core CPUs were common.

Is there a way I can prove the JVM is locked up, and that the web application is running as fast as it possible can?

Comment: I would start by taking a thread dump of the jvm to see if there are any propriatery code locking threads and exhausting the pool.  You can use jstack for this in the bin folder of your jdk.

Comment: What exact version of JBoss 5? Which Java? How many users? How much memory?

Comment: Jboss 5.1.0 GA, Java 6_38, 15,000 users. 16Gb(It never reaches max memory.)

Comment: How many concurrent users? How big is the database connection pool? I found with JBoss CMP it was often necessary to use their [Instance per Transaction Policy](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/Advanced_Configurations_and_Optimizations-Instance_Per_Transaction_Policy.html) in order to protect against deadlocks. If you have non-trivial CMP relationships then deadlocking can become a problem.